# how can i reference to an object variable without passing it as parameter in python classes

Tags: python, class

I am try to reference an object variable inside the class without passing it in parameters but it is throwing error

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self):
        v = []
        v.append(name)
        v.append(email)


s = Sample()
s.name = "xxxx"
s.email = "ss@ss.com"
print s.v
```

error:

```
NameError: global name 'name' is not defined
```

I am assigning the variable name in the object now how can i call it inside the class without adding parameters to function

Answer (score 1):

if you absolutely must avoid attributes:

```
class  Sample:
    def  __init__(self):
        self.v  =  []

    def  addName(self,  name):
        self.v.append(name)

    def  addEmail(self,  email):
        self.v.append(email)

s  =  Sample()
s.addName("xxxx")
s.addEmail("abc@def.com")
print(s.v)
```

Comment: is there any way to remove this name, email from here def __init__(self, name, email)

Comment: it's usually bad practice to exclude attributes from the class. is it because you're not able to provide values for name & email when you instantiate Sample?

Comment: name and email is sample but i have a big list of variable where i dont want to receive all of them using parameters

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this is to use decorators and `@property`:

```
class Sample(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = [None, None]

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.v[0]


    @property
    def email(self):
        return self.v[1]

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.v[0] = value


    @email.setter
    def email(self, value):
        self.v[1] = value


s = Sample()
s.name = "xxxx"
s.email = "ss@ss.com"
print s.v
```

Notes:

- Your class must be extending `object` explicitly in python 2 for this to work
- `@property` decorated methods are working as "getters" and return a value
- `@<name>.setter` is a setter method responsible for setting `<name>` member, so `@email.setter` sets the email and is being invoked when `x.email = ...` is called

The above may be a bit long-winded but allows for a clean API which hides the details from the user... Some people do prefer to add `get/set_name` methods to be more explicit but the above is more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements are dynamic, you can create attributes at run time like,

```
class Sample:
   pass


s = Sample()
setattr(s,"name","chanda")
setattr(s,"email","xyz@gmail.com")
setattr(s,"v",[s.name,s.email])

print(s.name) #chanda
print(s.email) #xyz@gmail.com
print(s.v) #['chanda', 'xyz@gmail.com']

print(s.__dict__) #{'email': 'xyz@gmail.com', 'v': ['chanda', 'xyz@gmail.com'], 'name': 'chanda'}
```